# Cross domain ajax request with jQuery not sending cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

The internet is littered with this type of request, but I'm asking it again because all the answers seem to be circa 2014. I have similar issues, but none of the old fixes work now, so I'm not sure if there is something new needed in 2020 (and beyond).

I'm trying to make a call from `domainA.com` to `domainB.com`. The user is authenticated on `domainB.com`, which is stored in a cookie on that domain.

I have administrative access to both domains, so I can make changes on either end, as needed.

Here is my jQuery ajax call used on a `domainA.com` site:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://domainB.com/endpoint",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }}
)
```

I've also tried additional properties such as:

- `crossDomain: true`
- `dataType: "json"`

The `domainB.com` site receives the request, **but with no cookies are on the request**.

The **request headers** are as follows:

```
host -> domainB-host
connection -> close
accept -> */*
sec-fetch-dest -> empty
user-agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
dnt -> 1
origin -> https://domainA.com
sec-fetch-site -> cross-site
sec-fetch-mode -> cors
referer -> https://domainA.com/
accept-encoding -> gzip, deflate, br
accept-language -> en-US,en;q=0.9
```

On `domainB.com` I'm also setting the following **response headers**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domainA.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin
```

Any ideas why the `domainB.com` cookies are not passed along in the request made from `domainA.com` when CORS is (I think) properly setup?

**UPDATE 1**
This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome (on Mac). I had previously been testing in Firefox as well, but it was not working. With the above configurations, it does in fact work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is related to Chrome's changes in version 80:

- [Cookies default to SameSite=Lax](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592)
- [Reject insecure SameSite=None cookies](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032)

There's a really good writeup by Troy Hunt [here](https://www.troyhunt.com/promiscuous-cookies-and-their-impending-death-via-the-samesite-policy/).

In short, the only cookies that will be passed now are those that have `SameSite=None` and `Secure` set on them. So the cookie will need to be set like this:

`Set-Cookie: cookie-name=cookie-value; SameSite=None; secure`

These are now the only cookies that will be passed by Chrome for cross site requests.